# Get a list of all public video ID s for vimeo account

Tags: python-3.x, vimeo, vimeo-api, pyvimeo

I have a free Vimeo account and few public videos. I need to download those videos.

I can download a public video given its id with **vimeo_dl**.

What I am trying is to get the list of video URIs or ids from my account. The official doc only explains uploading https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py

I tried to use the following, but it always returns an empty list.

```
import vimeo

client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
  token='dd8df####',
  key='2d0c6c###',
  secret='39CJ5M#####'
)

print("sending request")
response = client.get('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?sort=date&per_page=1').json() 
print("request done")
print(response)
```

Output:

```
sending request
request done
{'total': 0, 'page': 1, 'per_page': 1, 'paging': {'next': None, 'previous': None, 'first': '/me/videos?sort=date&per_page=1&page=1', 'last': '/me/videos?sort=date&per_page=1&page=1'}, 'data': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

/me endpoint requires user authentication. I'm not familiar with that github library but it has documentation for authentication and some of it is missing in your code: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py#authentication